# Cannot customize default Ext.Price decimal length on screen SOOrder

Tags: acumatica

I created new Project and customized it.

-ExtPrice (Customized Existing Field)

```
 [PXDBDecimal(5)]
 [PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal,"0.0")]
```

-SQL Server

```
 ALTER TABLE dbo.SOLine
 ALTER COLUMN CuryLineAmt decimal(19, 5) NULL
```

After then I publish that project but I see no changing on screen SOOrder that default still Ext.Price decimal length 4.

Comment: how you customized the existing field? using cache attached event?

Comment: @Hybridzz, I can't find it because after I customized Existing field and Sql server nothing changed.

Comment: you mentioned that you have done this '-ExtPrice (Customized Existing Field)' by what method you did? using website customization option or Cache attached event for the graph extension? Also if you did through website, did you publish it?

Comment: @Hybridzz, I use customization Projects then sql server, and publish it. But it doesn't change.

Comment: ok, but even if you want to change the decimal places, i dont think it will be correct to only change a single field in the system as all the fields max available precision is up to 4.

Comment: @Hybridzz, but I used to customize the other field's length and it changed when I publish but customize decimal it not effect. So do you have any idea how to change the fields max available precision is up to 5?

Comment: In acumatica, there is an option to set the price/cost decimal places. Did you try that? Organization > Organization structure > Configure > branches

Comment: @Hybridzz, sorry i'm junior about Acumatica so sometimes I asked a lot. But what the problem if I cannot change the Decimal Precision? I can't put it over 5.

Comment: @Hybridzz, it's okay now, Thanks!!!

Comment: so how did you solve it? Why i am not recommending customization of that single field is because, it will make you many more troubles if you just customize precision of only one field.

Comment: But I got the problem too when I change Decimal Precision in rganization > Organization structure > Configure > branches, the textbox showed 5 decimals and in SOOrder screen (Ext.Price) now is 0.00000 yet if I don't customize with Customization Projects, it will convert my Ext.Price: 1.12345 to 1.12350.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In acumatica 5.3, there is an option to set the price/cost decimal places. Did you try that?

> Organization > Organization structure > Configure > branches